# Azure App Service Container keeps on restarting

Tags: azure, docker, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I created an azure app Service running a docker container.

but the container seems to be restarting all the time:
2020-01-09 07:21:56.543 INFO  - Container XXX for site xxx initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
2020-01-09 07:22:01.559 ERROR - Container for xxx site xxx is unhealthy, Stopping site.
2020-01-09 07:22:01.559 INFO  - Stoping site xxx because it is not healthy.

As it is a ressource intensive application it can be that the Service is not responding quickly.

i already tried to add the following Setting:

{
    "name": "CONTAINER_AVAILABILITY_CHECK_MODE",
    "value": "Off",
    "slotSetting": false
  }

but with no effect.

Comment: Do you try to scale up the service plan?

Comment: yes and it is still doing it, i want to switch of the Health check

Comment: Do you check if the image can run well locally?

Comment: Yes i checked it and it is running well

Comment: How do you deploy the image to Azure Web App? What steps do you follow?

Comment: i was pulling it directly from docker hub

Comment: Can you share the link? Maybe I can test it for you.

Comment: sure it is Apache drill:

source docker hub
repository public
tag apache/drill:1.17.0
startexpression: -i --detach -t apache/drill:1.17.0 /bin/bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Dockerfile of the image apache/drill:1.17.0 you used, it does not expose the port 8047 to access outside. And there are two ways to expose the port that displayed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#your-container-must-respond-to-an-http-pingapplies-to-web-app-for-containers) and then you can access outside if you want. So the second way is suitable for this situation, and when you set the environment variable `WEBSITES_PORT` with value `8047`, then you can access the web app outside. Here is the screenshot which works fine on my side:

[image]

**Update:**

It seems the image needs an interactive mode and the docker command to run it should be `docker run -i --name drill-1.17.0 -p 8047:8047 --detach -t apache/drill:1.17.0 /bin/bash` or another similar command with an interactive mode. Or it would stop in a few munites later. But you cannot change the command that runs the image in Web App, so you also cannot use an interactive mode in Web App for the image.

So the solution is that you need to create a custom image to keep it on running state base on the image `apache/drill:1.17.0`. Then it will work well.

Comment: here are the Settings i use: [
  {
    "name": "CONTAINER_AVAILABILITY_CHECK_MODE",
    "value": "Off",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL",
    "value": "https://index.docker.io",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_RETENTION_DAYS",
    "value": "1",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE",
    "value": "false",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITES_PORT",
    "value": "8047",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]

Comment: @StefanS See the update in my answer. I think you test the image with the interactive mode. So it runs well locally.